# How to use 'input_shape' in Conv1D() function?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I have one million rows of data with six features and three classes.

```
6.442  6.338  7.027  8.789 10.009 12.566  A
6.338  7.027  5.338 10.009  8.122 11.217  A
7.027  5.338  5.335  8.122  5.537  6.408  B
5.338  5.335  5.659  5.537  5.241  7.043  B
5.659  6.954  5.954  8.470  9.266  9.334  C
6.954  5.954  6.117  9.266  9.243 12.200  C
5.954  6.117  6.180  9.243  8.688 11.842  A
6.117  6.180  5.393  8.688  5.073  7.722  A
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

I want to feed this dataset into a CNN.

So, I wrote the following Keras code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=n_hidden_1, kernel_size=3, activation='sigmoid', 
        input_shape=(1, num_features)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=n_hidden_2, kernel_size=3, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

This code is giving me the following error:

```
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for 
'{{node conv1d/conv1d}} 
= Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1]
, explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true]
(conv1d/conv1d/ExpandDims, conv1d/conv1d/ExpandDims_1)' with input shapes
: [?,1,1,6], [1,3,6,64].
```

**Edit:** Then, I modified the model as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=n_hidden_1, kernel_size=3, activation='sigmoid', 
    input_shape=(n_hidden_1, num_features, 1)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=n_hidden_2, kernel_size=3, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(3))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

Now I am getting the following error message:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer max_pooling1d is incompatible with the 
layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: 
    (None, 64, 2, 64)
```

**What am I writing wrong and why is it wrong?**

Comment: You can either try reducing the `kernel_size` to 2 or remove one of the `Conv1D` or `MaxPooling1D` layers.

Comment: As the sequence length is only 6, the size of the outputs of the Conv1D layer become smaller progressively, as it goes through them. After reaching a particular size, we can't perform max pooling on it

Comment: Add a Flatten layer after the Conv1D layer.

Comment: @user366312 What is the shape of `x_train` when you pass it to the `model.fit()`?

Comment: @Kaveh, *What is the shape of x_train when you pass it to the model.fit()?* -- a vector of vectors. Each inner vector has 6 columns and 1 row. The outer vector has 1 million entries.

Comment: @user366312 Specify input shape like `input_shape=(6,1)` and also add `padding="same"` argument to at least one of your `Conv1D` layers.

Comment: @Kaveh, `ValueError: Input 0 of layer max_pooling1d is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 256)`.

Comment: @user366312 If your input to Conv1D is a 3D, then the output is 3D, and it should work. But your error message says MaxPool1D received 2D!. Please comment MaxPool layer to avoid getting error and attach `model.summary()`. then I can say what is wrong.

Comment: @Kaveh, hey bro, I forgot to ask one thing. Why did we add one extra dimensions to `train_x` and `validate_x` ?

Comment: @user366312 Since, Conv1D expects 3D input, and your input is 2D (80000,6). In order to prepare it for Conv1D we can add another extra dimension. Otherwise, you get error.

Comment: @Kaveh, now, my model is running without max-pooling. What do I need to do if I want to add max-pooling?  `ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1d_1 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 384)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Conv1D` and `MaxPool1D` expect input shape like `(n_batches, n_steps, n_features)`. So, input shape should be like `input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)`. And if you want to consider 6 as steps, then it could be like `input_shape=(6,1)`.

1. For adding last dimension try this:

```
train_X = np.expand_dims(train_x, axis=-1)
validate_x = np.expand_dims(validate_x, axis=-1)
```

2. Since each convolution layer, with default padding valid, subtract `n_steps` by 2, then your second dimension shape change is like:

- input -> 6
- After first `Conv1D` -> 4
- After second `Conv1D` -> 2

And you can not apply a `MaxPool1D` by 3 pool size. Either you can change pool size to 2, or add `padding="same"` to one of your convolution layers:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(6, 1)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='sigmoid')) 
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2)) # change to 2 or add `padding="same"` to the conv layers
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()
```

Summary:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 4, 64)             256       
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_3 (Conv1D)            (None, 2, 64)             12352     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 2, 64)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1 (None, 1, 64)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 3)                195       
=================================================================
Total params: 13,258
Trainable params: 13,258
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```